# How do I split a string with white space in Google Sheet that include white space in output

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following string :

`A||B| |C||||| |` and I want the following output `A|.|B|.|C|.|.|.|.|.|`

When I'm doing this `=SUBSTITUTE("A||B| |C||||| |","||","|.|")` I have the following output `A|.|B| |C|.||.|| |`. why not all the space between `|` are filled with `•` ?

The main idea behind this is to replace each white space with a specific character so I can use the Split function (which doesn't output white space otherwise)

Comment: Why do you need replace the white space at all. You can simply use the split function with \\s as the delimiter in java.

Answer (score 0):

It's because there's no white space between `||`. It's just two consecutive `|` . Sometimes there's white space. Other times, there's none.

This will give your desired output:

```
   =SUBSTITUTE(trim(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE("A||B| |C||||| |","(\|)","|•"),"(•)(\w)","$2"))," ","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

`=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1," ?(\|)",".$1"),"([A-Z]+)\.","$1")`

or

`=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1," ?(\|)",".$1"),"(\w+)\.","$1")`

where A1 = `A||B| |C||||| |`